# Is subprocess cross platform?

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I am writing a Network Monitoring application using PySide and Qt. I want to make it cross platform.  I am using tcpdump and nmap for a lot of the monitoring portion. There is a nmap python module, but there is no tcpdump python module(that I know of), which means I would have to use subprocess to run tcpdump.  So my question is, if I use subprocess, will it work on all platforms (windows, linux, mac) or is it specific to a certain platform?

Comment: So long as you are not calling platform specific processes then yes, its cross platform.

Comment: Ignoring the main question for a moment, note that if you are building your own tool you might want to use `libpcap` (which `tcpdump` uses) instead of calling `tcpdump` directly. And then you will find Python bindings as well more abstract code based on it.

Answer (score 5):

The `subprocess` module is cross-platform. It works on POSIX (incl. Mac OS X) *and* Windows platforms.

There are some caveats and differences that apply only to Windows, all documented in the [module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).